# Change background list item on click in dynamic nested List

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, list

I have nested lists draw in run time dynamic from database in away like this  :

```
<div class="list"><ul>
<li>
    listA
    <ul>
        <li>Alist1</li>
        <li>Alist2</li>
        <li>Alist3</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
    listB
    <ul>
        <li>BList1</li>
        <li>BList2</li>
        <li>BList3</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

i want to change the back ground of list item when clicked but it change style of the all nested list by the following method :

```
        var $li = $('#list li').click(function () {
        $li.removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
```

using this style :

```
li.selected {
background-color: aqua;}
```

I know that i should use  the direct descendant operator (>) to force change to parent only but my problem that list is drawn dynamically and I can't limit its levels and nested list.

is there away to always force only clicked item to be changed only ?

Comment: what you've tried so far??

Comment: You want to set a background on which li ? the first nested li after your first ul ?

Comment: @KolaCaine i want to change background of every list item when I click only but what happened is that all nested lists in clicked list item style changed

Comment: adding a `is-active` class CSS for example and put this class when you click and after on your CSS you put the background or if you want a dynamic background you change the background property in your JS file you understand ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1-** You can't use `#list` while your list have a class `list` not id `list` with classes you need to use dot not `#`

**2-** You need to use `>` like `$('.list > ul > li')`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('ul > li').on('click' , function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    //$('li > ul').hide();
    $(this).find(' > ul').slideDown();
    $(this).parent('ul').find('li').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
  });
});
```

```css
ul{
  background : #fff;
}
li > ul{
  display : none;
}
li.selected{
  background : red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
  <ul>
    <li>
        listA
        <ul>
            <li>Alist1
              <ul>
                  <li>Alist1-1</li>
                  <li>Alist1-2</li>
                  <li>Alist1-3</li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Alist2</li>
            <li>Alist3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        listB
        <ul>
            <li>BList1</li>
            <li>BList2</li>
            <li>BList3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

-- It'll be better to work with `<a>` see the next example

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a').on('click' , function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var GetLi = $(this).closest('li');
    var GetBigUL = $(this).closest('ul');
    var GetNextUL = $(this).next('ul');
    GetBigUL.find('a').next('ul').not(GetNextUL).slideUp();
    GetNextUL.slideDown();
    GetBigUL.find('li').removeClass('selected');
    GetLi.addClass('selected');
  });
});
```

```css
ul{
  background : #fff;
}
li > ul{
  display : none;
}
li.selected{
  background : red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
  <ul>
    <li>
        <a>listA</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
              <a>Alist1</a>
              <ul>
                  <li><a>Alist1-1</a></li>
                  <li><a>Alist1-2</a></li>
                  <li><a>Alist1-3</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a>Alist2</a></li>
            <li><a>Alist3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>listB</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a>BList1</a></li>
            <li><a>BList2</a></li>
            <li><a>BList3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: this is the same behavior .. it change the parent and it's children i only want to change the clicked item not it's children. although my problem is when it draw dynamic where i can't determine the umber of nested lists.

Comment: @AhmedEmad this code not change the children .. Keep in mind the all element has no background by default .. so while you didn't set the background for any nested li it will show the same background of its parent

Comment: @AhmedEmad I update my answer .. as you can see after set the nested ul background just the direct  li background changed

Comment: thanks mohamed for your help but it force to color only the parent. I want to color any list item on click and remain the other items not colored not only for parents

Comment: @AhmedEmad  Its not that easy .. I believe there's another easy ways to do that but it's not on my mind right now .. So check the updated answer I think its near to what you looking for .. hope so

Comment: @AhmedEmad see the updated answer .. using <a> makes everything simple .. Good Luck :)

Comment: @Mohammed-yousef Thanks this answer is the nearest one I found .

Comment: you're totally welcome @AhmedEmad .. Have a great day :-)